# APP-SCRIPT Condition to check if date entered is before today's date

Tags: google-apps-script

```
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "m/dd/yyyy")
if (formS.getRange("B7").getValue() != " " && formS.getRange("B7").getValue() != date) 
 { 
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please Enter A Valid Date"); 
  return
 }
```

Trying to make the condition above check if the cell is not empty and that it does not contain a date prior to Today's Date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function myfunk() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const formS = ss.getSheetByName('formS');
  const dtv = new Date(new Date().getFullYear(), new Date().getMonth(), new Date().getDate()).valueOf();
  if (!formS.getRange("B7").isBlank() && new Date(formS.getRange("B7").getValue()).valueOf() < dtv) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please Enter A Valid Date");
    return;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Checking Dates in Apps Script

In general you can use the Date object as you would in normal JavaScript code. There are just one main thing to bear in mind if your script needs to be sensitive to timezones.

The timezone is defined in the manifest:

[image]

This cannot be changed dynamically. So if you need to be sensitive to them, then you will need to manage the offsets in your code.

#### Your script

This line:

```js
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-8", "m/dd/yyyy")
```

Returns a *string*. Not a date object, so you can't compare it to another date object, such as what is returned from a sheet value if it is formatted as a date.

You could use Regex or `split` to get the year and month and compare it that way, but then you may run into issue when you use the script on the 1st of January. This is because by simply comparing the year, month and date of 31/12/2021 with 01/01/2022, then your conditional statements would be a bit tricky. Possible, but maybe a bit hard to read.

#### Initializing to midnight

What follows is one approach to take to carry out this comparison in a relatively simple way.

It seems convenient to get a date object initialized to `00:00:00` of today. Then you can quickly compare the date using Unix time.

```js
var now = new Date()
now.setHours(0)
now.setMinutes(0)
now.setSeconds(0)
now.setMilliseconds(0)
```

You can also do this in a more concise way like this:

```js
var now = new Date()
now.setHours(0,0,0,0);
```

Then you can use the `getTime()` method on the date objects to get Unic time in milliseconds and compare them.

```js
var dateToCheck = formS.getRange("B7").getValue()
  if (
    !(dateToCheck instanceof Date) || // If value is not instance of a Date object
    dateToCheck.getTime() <= now.getTime() // If date is before 00:00:00 today.
  ) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Please Enter A Valid Date");
    return
  }
}
```

Which seems like a concise way to do the comparison you are looking for.

#### References

- [Apps Script Dates](https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates)
- [JS Date object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)